# JavaScript equivalent of PHP function: array_flip

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any shortcut to accomplishing the equivalent of [PHP's array_flip function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) in JavaScript or does it have to be done via brute force looping?

It has to be used for dozens of arrays so even small speedups will probably add up.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't think there's one built in.  Example implementation [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/array_flip:317), though `:)`.

```
function array_flip( trans )
{
    var key, tmp_ar = {};

    for ( key in trans )
    {
        if ( trans.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
        {
            tmp_ar[trans[key]] = key;
        }
    }

    return tmp_ar;
}
```

Comment: @pianoman - I added the hasOwnProperty check. Hope you don't mind =)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend phpjs.org: the code quality is underwhelming and some functions don't work in IE at all! If you want to program in JS, learn it!

Comment: also keep in mind that this only works reliably if the property values have a unique string representation

Comment: @Christoph - See your point, but if the properties aren't unique, one really shouldn't be flipping the array to begin with ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 14):

### ES6 version

```
const example = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' };

const flipped = Object.entries(example)
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({ ...obj, [value]: key }), {}); 

// flipped is {foo: 'a', bar: 'b'}
```

### ES5 version

```
var example = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}; 

var flipped = Object.keys(example)                //get the keys as an array
    .reduce(function(obj, key) {                  //build up new object
        obj[example[key]] = key;
        return obj;
    }, {});                                       //{} is the starting value of obj

// flipped is {foo: 'a', bar: 'b'}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) _.invert

```
_.invert([1, 2]) 
//{1: '0', 2: '1'}

_.invert({a: 'b', c: 'd'}) 
//{b: 'a', d: 'c'}
```

Comment: Good solution, but how would you cast the string value, which are the array indices, to type `number`? Call another method like `map`?

Comment: @ConAntonakos yes, I guess ```_.mapObject(_.invert([1, 2]), function (d) {return +d})``` will do

Comment: For those using lodash, it has `invert` too.

Answer (score 2):

with jQuery:

```
var array_flipped={};
$.each(array_to_flip, function(i, el) {
  array_flipped[el]=i;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about Objects not Arrays

```
function flip(o){
    var newObj = {} 
    Object.keys(o).forEach((el,i)=>{
        newObj[o[el]]=el;
    });
    return newObj;
}
```

Otherwise it could be

```
function flip(o){

    var newObj = {} 

    if (Array.isArray(o)){

        o.forEach((el,i)=>{
            newObj[el]=i;
        });

    } else if (typeof o === 'object'){

        Object.keys(o).forEach((el,i)=>{
            newObj[o[el]]=el;
        });

    }

    return newObj;

}
```

Comment: The .map function doesn't work at all, it only creates an array of ascending numbers from 0 to length-1 regardless of array content.

Answer (score 1):

The current top answer didn't work as expected for me because key values are offset +1. (and so the returned array tmpArr(0) is also always undefined. So I subtracted 1 from key value and it worked as expected.

```
function array_flip2 (trans) {
  var key
  var tmpArr = {}

  for (key in trans) {
    if (!trans.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue
    }
    tmpArr[trans[parseInt(key)]-1] = (key)
  }
  return tmpArr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Simple approach*

```js
const obj = { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
      keys = Object.keys(obj),
      values = Object.values(obj),
      flipped = {};
for(let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
    flipped[values[i]] = keys[i];
}
console.log(flipped);//{foo: "a", bar: "b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might flip keys and values this way:

```js
let arr = "abc".split('');

let flip = []
arr.forEach((n, i) => {
    flip[Object.values(arr)[i]] = Object.keys(arr)[i];
})

console.log(Object.keys(arr), Object.values(arr));
console.log(Object.keys(flip), Object.values(flip));
```

Depending on how large your initial array is you may want to store the keys/values in their own respective arrays.