# How could I iterate on object's attributes backwards in javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example I already have an object filled with ordered key-values, I can iterate its keys **forwards** with **for in** statement:

```
var keyvalues = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"};
for(var key in keyvalues)
{
   var value = keyvalues[key];
   .............
}
```

Now I want to iterate the keys **backwards** like *'key3', 'key2', 'key1'*, is there a magic way to do this?

Comment: Enumerating objects doesn't guarantee a specific *order*... You can use an array if you need to keep them in a specific order.

Comment: [There is also one discussion / post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586304/how-to-reverse-the-order-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Also something to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159277/array-flip-in-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### There is no guarantee of order in a `for... in` loop.

#### Wait, what?

There is no logic in 'order' of object keys. If you'd like, you can grab them and then use `.sort` on them. The [language specification](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4) tells us this explicitly in the `for...in` iteration algorithm:

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) is not specified.

#### What are your options:

In JavaScript, most of the time ordered lists are represented by **arrays**. You can us an array if like an ordered list in your case:

```
var values= ["key1","key2","key3"];
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
   values[i];// order is guaranteed here.
}
```

Since order is guaranteed you can also easily [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) it:

```
var values= ["key1","key2","key3"].reverse();//reverse is an array method
for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
   values[i];// order is guaranteed here.
}
```

If you already *have* an **object** you can grab its keys and  `.sort` them based on some criterion, for example - in a lexicographical order :

```
var obj = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"};
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort().reverse(); // see note
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    console.log(keys[i]);
}
// will output key3, key2, key1
```

<sub>note: you can pass a comparator to `.sort` and have it reverse it for you instead of chaining - which is probably better practice. I kept it this way for pedagogical purposes.</sub>

Comment: I believe that is no longer the case. for...in now always iterates over integer keys between 0 and 2^32-1 first in order of low to high, then over the rest of the keys in the same order that they were added to the object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `var keys = Objects.keys(keyvalues).sort()` to get all the keys of the object then just iterate through it backwords in a `for(int = keys.length;i>0;i--)` loop accessing the original object like so `value = object[keys[i]]` in the loop

**EDIT:** Added the `sort` function call to the array of keys returned by `Object.keys`.

Comment: The order returned by `Object.keys` is not guaranteed.

Comment: How would you iterate backwards through an **object** that has dynamically changing keys then?

Comment: @Legion You can sort them - see my answer. The fact the keys iterated in the order key1,key2,key3 is completely coincidental - it's implementation detail and may change any day.