# pivot or maybe grouping with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

orginal     date structure:

```
    [
        {
            "DateTimeUtc": "2016-02-02T12:00:00",
            "TMP": -0.4,
            "DPT": -2.6,
            "HUMIDEX": -3.16231537,

        },
        {
            "DateTimeUtc": "2016-02-02T13:00:00",
            "TMP": -0.2,
            "DPT": -2.8,
            "HUMIDEX": -3.00339675,
        },
         {
            "DateTimeUtc": "2016-02-02T14:00:00",
            "TMP": -0.3,
            "DPT": -2.7,
            "HUMIDEX": -13.00339675,
        },
.
.
.
    ]
```

Expected result:

```
     [
                   {
                "Hour": "DPT",
                "Feb  2 2016  5:00AM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  6:00AM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  7:00AM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  8:00AM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  9:00AM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016 10:00AM": -12,
                "Feb  2 2016 11:00AM": -14,
                "Feb  2 2016 12:00PM": -13,
                "Feb  2 2016  1:00PM": -12,
                "Feb  2 2016  2:00PM": -12,
                "Feb  2 2016  3:00PM": -12,
                "Feb  2 2016  4:00PM": -12,
                "Feb  2 2016  5:00PM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  6:00PM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  7:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016  8:00PM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  9:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016 10:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016 11:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  3 2016 12:00AM": -10,
                "Feb  3 2016  1:00AM": -10,
                "Feb  3 2016  2:00AM": -10,
                "Feb  3 2016  3:00AM": -10,
                "Feb  3 2016  4:00AM": -10
            },
            {
                "Hour": "Humidex",
                "Feb  2 2016  5:00AM": -13,
                "Feb  2 2016  6:00AM": -13,
                "Feb  2 2016  7:00AM": -13,
                "Feb  2 2016  8:00AM": -12,
                "Feb  2 2016  9:00AM": -13,
                "Feb  2 2016 10:00AM": -15,
                "Feb  2 2016 11:00AM": -17,
                "Feb  2 2016 12:00PM": -15,
                "Feb  2 2016  1:00PM": -14,
                "Feb  2 2016  2:00PM": -14,
                "Feb  2 2016  3:00PM": -13,
                "Feb  2 2016  4:00PM": -11,
                "Feb  2 2016  5:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016  6:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016  7:00PM": -9,
                "Feb  2 2016  8:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016  9:00PM": -9,
                "Feb  2 2016 10:00PM": -10,
                "Feb  2 2016 11:00PM": -11,
                "Feb  3 2016 12:00AM": -11,
                "Feb  3 2016  1:00AM": -12,
                "Feb  3 2016  2:00AM": -12,
                "Feb  3 2016  3:00AM": -13,
                "Feb  3 2016  4:00AM": -13
            },
.
.
.
        ]
```

Comment: That's surely not how the data looks by the time you get it in javascript ?

Comment: What is the raw format exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159277/array-flip-in-javascript

Comment: @epascarello I edit the question. please see the data structure. adeneo you too my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that is what you want.

```js
function getDate(date) {
    var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oc', 'Nov', 'Dec'][date.getMonth()],
        day = date.getDay(),
        year = date.getFullYear(),
        hours = date.getHours(),
        minutes = date.getMinutes(),
        ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

    day = day < 10 ? ' ' + day : day;
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    hours = hours < 10 ? ' ' + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    return month + ' ' + day + ' ' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
}

var data = [{ "DateTimeUtc": "2016-02-02T12:00:00", "TMP": -0.4, "DPT": -2.6, "HUMIDEX": -3.16231537 }, { "DateTimeUtc": "2016-02-02T13:00:00", "TMP": -0.2, "DPT": -2.8, "HUMIDEX": -3.00339675 }, { "DateTimeUtc": "2016-02-02T14:00:00", "TMP": -0.3, "DPT": -2.7, "HUMIDEX": -13.00339675 }],
    cols = ['DPT', 'HUMIDEX'],
    pivot = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        cols.forEach(function (k, i) {
            r[i] = r[i] || { Hour: k };
            r[i][getDate(new Date(a.DateTimeUtc))] = a[k];
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(pivot, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I update the question with the format of the data coming to js. I want pivot them based on datetimeutc property.

Comment: I have attached an image. I am looking for something different .please see the attachment.

Comment: please render your data with `JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4)` and insert that into the question. the image makes not clear what you want.

Comment: doen. please check the question,

Comment: done. cleaned the question and added the original data structure.  thanks for looking into this Nina.

Comment: I will let you know if i have any questions.